# How to get the data read from excel file and display in my view?

Tags: excel, laravel

In my controller, i will load the excel file when click on the button.

```
Excel::load(Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath(), function ($reader) use($arr){
// How can i get the $reader data and pass back to view?
});

return redirect()->back()->with('reader',...);
```

In my view, i will display the data get from the excel file

```
@if(!empty(Session::get('reader')))
    $(function() {
    @foreach(session()->get('reader')  as $key=>$row)
    alert('{{$row['id']}}');
    @endforeach
});
@endif
```

Can any guide me how can i make it to pass the data back to the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you directly store result into array. so your code should be like

```
$reader= \Excel::load(Input::file('import_file'))->toArray();
        return redirect()->back()->with('reader', $reader);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Excel::load(Input::file('import_file'), function ($reader) {
    //Read and get excel rows...
    var $arrExcelData = array();
    $arrExcelData = $reader->toArray();
    return redirect()->back()->with('arrExcelData', $arrExcelData);
});
```

**Render data:**

```
@if(!empty(Session::get('arrExcelData')))
    @foreach(session()->get('arrExcelData')  as $key=>$row)
        print_r($row);
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: It will return blank page if put inside the Excel::load

Comment: I've recently update the my answer, check with recent one. Thanks